# How do I add cn;phonetic attribute to ldap schema?

Tags: java, ldap, openldap

My ldap version is 2.4.42.0, when I tried to add an entry, which has an indispensible attribute called cn;phonetic, to the server, I received error code 17.

Any modification in core.schema around cn is not possible, and when I tried to input some commands to modify the cn attribute like this one:https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap/issues/321, I kept received invalid dn error.

My question is, what should I do to make cn;phonetic available on the server?

By the way , My root dn is something like cn=testadmin,o=test.com

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that ldap has deprecated some configuration options after version 2.3.
According to this page [OpenLDAP using OLC](https://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html) , I use OLC to set olcattributeoptions in cn=config.ldif as:

**olcAttributeOptions: lang- phonetic**

Then I can add cn;phonetic attribute to my server.